# How do I use an infinite amount of structs for a function's parameter?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I'm writing a very simple OBJ exporter in C++ (for VC6, as I am writing for an old project that only compiles there.)

Right now, I'm stuck on figuring out how to use an infinite amount of structs to make a vertices position line. That may sound a bit silly, but this is my first functioning program written in C++, so I don't know the concepts very well.

I'm assuming I'm doing it wrong, as there's nothing I can find on the Internet for what I'm trying to do.

Here's my header's struct code:

```cpp
struct PointList {
        float X;
        float Y;
        float Z;
    };
```

..and the actual OBJ export function's code:

```cpp
void OBJEXP::WriteOBJ(OBJEXP::PointList Points, std::string File) // Writes an OBJ.
{
    ofstream    output(File + ".obj");

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Points); i += 1)
    {
        output << "v " + to_string(Points.X) + " " + to_string(Points.Y) + " " + to_string(Points.Z) + "\n";
    }
    output.close();
    cout << "All done\n";
}
```

My main file (meant to test the code out, this is going to be run every time I save a file otherwise:)

```
OBJEXP::PointList POINTZ;

int main()
{
    POINTZ.X = 1.0f;
    POINTZ.Y = 5.5f;
    POINTZ.Z = 2.0f;
    OBJEXP::WriteOBJ(POINTZ, "testobject");
    std::cout << "Execution done\n";
}
```

My OBJ file looks like this:

```
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
v 1.000000 5.500000 2.000000
```

which obviously isn't very correct.

Comment: You *do* know that `infinite` is not a number, right?

Comment: `PointList` isn't a very good name since it is not a list of anything. Consider renaming that to `Point` and using `std::vector<Point>` as a collection of them.

Comment: Note that MSVC 6.0 was released in [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#6.0_(1998)).  It is an ancient version of C++ (probably not even compliant with C++98, let alone any more recent version of the standard).

Comment: You cannot use an *infinite* amount of anything in a computer program. On the other hand, a program could be designed for an *unlimited* or *unbounded* amount of something. That is, any limits are placed by factors outside the program (such as limited memory).

Comment: @wallyk I know. I don't literally mean infinite, bad wording on my part. I'm probably doing this wrong though

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know, as I said, I'm unfortunately stuck with that as the only way to compile this project.

Comment: My comment was as much aimed at other commentators — it's not clear to me that MSVC 6 would understand `std::vector<PointList>` (or `std::vector<Point>`).

Comment: It would be much faster to re-make or upgrade the project with a modern compiler. MSVC 14.28 (VS 2019) is free and can convert old project versions to the current versions in-place.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do here to be honest. The for loop is iterating `sizeof(Points)` times, which will be the number of bytes the struct takes up. 3 (floats) x 4 (bytes per float) = 12, which is the number of lines your program output. But of course each time, it outputs the same X,Y, and Z.

Comment: If `std:vector` isn't available as others mentioned, you can go full on C, and use a pointer to an array and a size: `void OBJEXP::WriteOBJ(OBJEXP::PointList *Points, int num_points, std::string File)`.

Comment: @Casey While I would love to upgrade the project, building will error on Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Although it was not perfect Visual Studio 6 contained a full implementation of the standard library at the time. vector, string, set, map, etc. We shipped many games using it before eventually moving to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use vector :D

```
void OBJEXP::WriteOBJ(std::vector<OBJEXP::PointList> Points, std::string File) {
    ofstream output(File + ".obj");
    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i += 1) {
        output << "v " + to_string(Points[i].X) + " " + to_string(Points[i].Y) + " " + to_string(Points[i].Z) + "\n";
    }
    output.close();
    cout << "All done\n";
}
```

main code:

```
OBJEXP::PointList POINTZ;
int main() {
    POINTZ.X = 1.0f;
    POINTZ.Y = 5.5f;
    POINTZ.Z = 2.0f;

    std::vector tmp;
    tmp.push_back(POINTZ);
    OBJEXP::WriteOBJ(tmp, "testobject");
}
```

Comment: Did MSVC 6 support the STL?  It was released before the C++98 standard was finalized, which doesn't stop it having the support, but also doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: Yes, it had a full implementation of the STL at the time. `std::vector tmp;` seems like a typo, and you'd be better off with `const std::vector<OBJEXP::PointList>& Points` for your function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of an ancient compiler not-withstanding, the format of .OBJ does not include the number of verts/uvs/normals/faces before the list.

You must read the file twice: first to count the number of verts/uvs/normals/faces that appear, then again to parse the actual values.

A modern compiler makes this trivial with the use of `std::string`, `std::stringstream` and `std::vector`. Using C-style strings, arrays, and FILE* would make this a nightmare.